# Spring application with JMSListener doesnt shut down

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-jms

I have a Spring application running on Tomcat.
When I try to shut it down, it doesnt seem to do that.

Here is a screenshot from intellij:
[image]

Here is what my code looks like:

```
@Service
public class QueueMsgConsumer
{

    @JmsListener(destination = Keys.QUEUE_NAME)
    public void processMsg(TextMessage message)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

It seems that using @JmsListener starts a non-daemon thread that does not stop when tomcat wants to shutdown.

What is the right way to shut down my application?

**Update:**

While adding a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' with 'setDaemon(true)` does result in an eventual shutdown after a minute or so, it still seems to be not graceful. Turning on 'trace' level logging i see this:

```
11:46:04,190  INFO localhost-startStop-1 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor:356 - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
11:46:04,191 DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor:226 - Asking bean 'org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry' of type [class org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry] to stop
11:46:34,197  WARN localhost-startStop-1 support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor:373 - Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483647 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry]
```

Comment: Can you paste code here?

Comment: ok added the code for my jmslistener

Comment: `@JmsListener` is just the object that processes the message. It doesn't deal with thread creation. It looks like the threads are handled by Amazon java messaging.

Comment: seems issue is with the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` class

Answer (score 0):

[SPR-14233](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14233) was fixed in Spring Core 4.2.6